# Slick carousel when last slide has 1 item and slidesToShow is greater than slidesToScroll then slide is not working at last on click of arrows

Tags: html, jquery, css, slick.js

I have total of 9 slides and I would like to scroll 4 items on click of arrows. Slides to show should be 5.
When you execute below code, you see on last slide when we click on arrow it's not scrolling.

1. Total slides 9
2. slidestoshow 5
3. slidestoscroll 4

I have total of 9 slides and I would like to scroll 4 items on click of arrows. Slides to show should be 5.
When you execute below code, you see on last slide when we click on arrow it's not scrolling.

====================================================================

Code sandbox below. Please open the view in new window.
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-almeida-kn98f6?file=/index.js